# MySQL index based on last digit of INT column

Tags: mysql, indexing, mariadb, partitioning

Is it possible to create an index in MySQL for the last digit of an int column?

Based on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21837451/mysql-table-partition-based-on-last-digit-of-a-column-id)  i have created partitions based on last digit of an int column

```
CREATE TABLE partition_test(
  textfiled INT,
  cltext TEXT,
  reindexedAt TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  indexedAt TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  status TINYINT(2),
  postId INT)
PARTITION BY HASH(MOD(postId, 10))
PARTITIONS 10;
```

I'm trying to create an index for the last digit of postId for optimizing queries time. Is there any way to do this or a simple index on postId is enough?

Some failed tries:

```
CREATE INDEX postLastDigit USING HASH ON partition_test (MOD(postId, 10));
(1064, u"You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'MOD(postId, 10))' at line 1")
```

and

```
CREATE INDEX postLastDigit ON partition_test (MOD(postId, 10));
(1064, u"You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'MOD(postId, 10))' at line 1")
```

**UPDATE:**
The table has more than 100M row.

My goal is to optimize queries like:

1)

```
SELECT cltext FROM partition_tables 
  WHERE postId in (<INT>, <INT>) 
  AND status IS NOT NULL
```

2)

```
SELECT cltext FROM partition_tables 
  WHERE postId in (<INT>, <INT>) 
  AND status IS NOT NULL
  AND reindexedAt BETWEEN (<DATE>, <DATE>)
```

MariaDB version: **10.1.23-MariaDB-9+deb9u1**

Comment: That's a bad idea. Besides, an essentially *random* partitioning isn't going to improve anything. It will *definitely* harm performance as the server will be forced to search all partitions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use virtual columns. In MariaDB 10.2, you can create index on [virtual aka generated column](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/generated-columns/), like this

```
 CREATE TABLE t (
  num int,
  last_digit int(1) AS (num % 10) VIRTUAL,
  KEY index_last_digit (last_digit)
)
```

Then you can use last_digit in your queries, i.e SELECT ... WHERE last_digit=1

In older versions of MariaDB, 5.2 to 10.1 , you'd need to specify *PERSISTENT* attribute rather than VIRTUAL, because non-persistent  generated columns could not be indexed.

Answer (score 1):

You have tagged your question with `mariadb` and `mysql`. If you are using a resonably recent version of MariaDB, you can use generated columns for indexing. If you are using MySQL, you can do the same if your MySQL version is at least 5.7.

If you are using a lower version of MySQL, you could create an additional column in your table where you store the last digit of `postId` for each row, and use that column for indexing / partitioning.

This would mean minimal changes to your application code: Before inserting or updating, get the last digit of `postId` first, and insert / update one more field. As an alternative, you eventually could use triggers to automatically fill that additional column.

Comment: from the beginning i was trying to avoid this alternative. I will wait a while for other possible answers otherwise i will accept yours. tnx Binarus

Comment: @SimakisPanagiotis: You can create a generated column ([Generated (Virtual and Persistent) Columns](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/generated-columns/)) and index it.

Comment: @SimakisPanagiotis the original idea is wrong. A random partitioning offers no benefits - a RAID array does a better job. You wouldn't need that weird index if you didn't use this weird partitioning scheme.

Comment: @wchiquito The OP used tags mariadb and mysql. He could implement what you propose provided that he uses MariaDB (which supports that since a long time), but probably not if he uses MySQL (because the feature has been introduced with MySQL 5.7 AFAIK, and that version has not made it yet into every Linux distrbution). But thanks for the hint, and +1. I'll edit my answer accordingly.

Comment: In fact, we do not have information about the version of MariaDB (or MySQL) used, that is why the link to the documentation, where it will be possible to determine the feasibility of the solution option depending on the version.

Answer (score 1):

What query are you trying to speed up?  Without any indexes on the table, *any* query will have to scan the entire table!  If you want speed, first look to indexing.

If your query is `SELECT ... WHERE post_id = 123`, your Partitioning might make it run about 10 times as fast.  But `INDEX(post_id)`, with or without partitioning, will make it run hundreds of times as fast.

Please provide the `SELECTs` so we can help you speed them up.

(OK, if you are just playing around with partitioning, the others have given you viable answers.)

"Partition Pruning" is rarely faster than a suitable index that starts with the pruning column.

After you solve your stated hashing problem, please report back whether the queries any faster than using an index.  Even pitted against an index, I predict partitioning will not run faster, and may even run a little slower.

Comment: A random partitioning like this will probably make the query run 10 times slower, not faster.